# How to show cached image while fresh image loading using Glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am loading a picture from remote server into ImageView with Glide. Server updates image every second and URL of this image is always constant. I need to show previously downloaded image from cache while new is downloading.

I am using this code to achieve it:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 ...
 loadImage(this, imageView, "http://server.com/path/to/script.php")
}

fun loadImage(context: Context, imageView: ImageView, url: String?) {
 Glide.with(context)
  .asBitmap()
  .load(url)
  .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
  .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
   override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
    updateImage(context, imageView, url, resource)
   }

   override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
    updateImage(context, imageView, url, null)
   }

   override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
  })
}

private fun updateImage(context: Context, imageView: ImageView, url: String?, placeholder: Bitmap?) {
 Glide.with(context)
  .setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().timeout(30000))
  .load(url)
  .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis())) // Force download most fresh image
  .placeholder(BitmapDrawable(context.resources, placeholder))
  .dontAnimate()
  .into(imageView)  
}
```

What I am expecting:

- show cached image
- download new image
- save new image into cache
- show new image

But actual behaviour is:

- show cached image which was loaded on first launch
- download new image
- cache is not updated
- show new image.

So the problem is that Glide caching only first image and never updates the cache. How to fix it?

Comment: I think what i understand from https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation#custom-cache-invalidation you need to use `StringSignature` to update the url and therefor force the cache bypass

Comment: @Jakoss As I know StringSignature is deprecated and ObjectKey using instead. I am using ObjectKey to force download. And it is downloading well but cache doesn't updated.

Comment: I want same thing